# How do I deploy from Eclipse (Windows) to Azure Web Apps for Linux, with automatic uploading of Linux-environment specific files?

Tags: eclipse, azure, maven

My application works well on my Windows laptop as an Eclipse Dynamic Project.

I deploy it to Azure Web Apps for Linux using Azure/Publish as Azure Web App.

The application deploys successfully.

There are however a couple of files which are Eclipse-environment specific, which need to be changed to be Linux-environment specific.

At the moment I am changing these manually, post-deployment, by using WinSCP and then restarting the Web App. Is there a way of uploading the Linux-environment specific files as part of the deployment?

One idea I had is to deploy using a [maven script](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/blob/develop/docs/web-app-samples.md#Web-App-on-Linux-with-Java-8-Tomcat)

```
<project>
   ...
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   ...
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>

               <!-- Web App information -->
               <resourceGroup>${RESOURCEGROUP_NAME}</resourceGroup>
               <appName>${WEBAPP_NAME}</appName>

               <!-- Deploy Web App to the existing App Service Plan -->
               <appServicePlanResourceGroup>${PLAN_RESOURCEGROUP_NAME}</appServicePlanResourceGroup>
               <appServicePlanName>${PLAN_NAME}</appServicePlanName>

               <!-- Java Runtime Stack for Web App on Linux-->
               <linuxRuntime>tomcat 8.5-jre8</linuxRuntime>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         ...
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

but then I don't know how to specify the eclipse-specific files in the script, and anyway I don't know if this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using DevOps pipeline for that custom requirement.

You could possible you **GitHub Actions** to take care of the Eclipse specific files:

https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy#create-azure-web-app-and-deploy-using-github-actions

Comment: Am I right in understanding this is two separate suggestions? Is the first suggestion to use https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/eclipse/ With regard to the second suggestion I use SVN for my repository and not GitHub